# Delphi REST library Post с ненужным Content-Type

Tags: delphi, rest, content-type

Посылаю Post-запрос
Http Analyzer показывает в Raw Stream, что 
Content-Type: application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded

application/json я добавил сам:

```
RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('Content-Type', 'application/json', pkHTTPHEADER,
 [poDoNotEncode]);
```

Как избавиться от **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**?

Из-за него, на сколько я понял, возникает ошибка "400 Bad Request"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы как-то неправильно строите запрос. Вот пример использования REST клиента:

```
uses
  REST.Types,
  REST.Client,
  IPPeerClient,
  System.SysUtils;

procedure DoTest;
var      
  VClient: TRESTClient;
  VRequest: TRESTRequest;
  VResponse: TRESTResponse;
begin
  VClient := TRESTClient.Create('http://httpbin.org');
  try
    VRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(VClient);
    VResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(VRequest);
    VRequest.Response := VResponse;
    VRequest.Resource := '/post';
    VRequest.Method := rmPOST;
    VRequest.Params.AddHeader('Connection', 'Close');
    VRequest.AddBody('{"one": "1"}', ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
    VRequest.Execute;

    Writeln(VResponse.Content);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(VClient);
  end;
end;
```

Ответ:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"one\": \"1\"}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,",
    "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8, *;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "12",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Embarcadero RESTClient/1.0"
  },
  "json": {
    "one": "1"
  },
  "origin": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```